# to compare sub-items in vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

**Overview of problem :**   I am using std::vector to hold objects of Subject. Now this vector contains lots  of         objects( with lots I mean 10-20 objects at max) .

These objects have string member values  like **category** and **sub_category**.

Both category and sub_category can have string which can be same of other objects's sub_category & category.

**Issue:** Now I want my std::vector to have only those objects **whose's sub_category are unique**. If category is not unique that's not a problem .

Secondly if we found 2 objects having same sub_category then we have to delete one of them from the vector.  we will delete it based on some rules example

Rules for deleting  are if
                  i) instance of Subject ->category = " Land " OR if category = "Jungle"   then delete other duplicate object ,
                  ii) if above condition doesn't match then delete either of them.

I am wondering , how would I compare the sub-items from the vector . For example

I have class say  Subject

```
class Subject
{
public :
// some constructors,
// functions to get ., set category and sub category
   std::String get_sub_category()   
   std::string get_category();

 private:
   std::string category;
  std::string sub_category;
}
```

I have vector which stores object of Subjects. example

```
vector<Subject> sub_vec;
```

Now what I want is to delete the object from  vector that has same sub_category
I am not looking for source code buT i need a starting point,?
example

say

```
    sub_vec[0] = Animal  object that has sub_category Tiger
    sub_vec [1] = Animal object   with Lion as sub category 
    sub_vec[2] = Forest object with sub_category Tiger
```

so what I want is to based on some conditions(which I can do )  remove either Forest or Animal object containing Tiger.
But for that how would I do comparison?

Thanks everyone for the help.  I have written the function and have checked it but I am sure there is a room for hell lot of improvement. May you guys please pin out  out my pitfalls.

```
 std::vector< Subject >copy_vector; // copy_vector conatins all the objects of SUbject with redundant sub_category


  for( std::vector< Subject >::iterator ii = copy_vector.begin() ; ii != copy_vector.end() ; ++ii )
  {
      sub_category = ii->get_sub_category();

      std::cout <<" sub_category-- in main for loop " << sub_category  << std::endl ;
      std::vector< Subject >::iterator it = ii+1;
      while( it != copy_vector.end() )
      {
            std::cout <<" the  size of copy _vector is = " << copy_vector.size() << std::endl ; // for debug purpose
          if( it->get_sub_category() == sub_category )
          {
              std::cout <<" we got a match here" << std::endl ;
              // since both are duplicate , we have to delete one of them. Rules for deleting  are if 
              i) instance of Subject ->category = " Land " OR if category = "Jungle"   then delete other duplicate object , 
              ii) if above condition doesn't match then delete either of them.

              if( ( it->get_category == "Land" ) || (  it->get_category == "Jungle" )  )
              {
                 std::cout <<" we are deleting it reference value  " << std::endl ;
                 it =  copy_vector.erase(ii);

                 // increment the counter 
                 ++ii;
              }
              else if( ( ii->get_category == "Land" ) || (  ii->get_category == "Jungle" )  )
              {
                 std::cout <<" we are deleting from copy_vector  " << std::endl ;
                 it =  copy_vector.erase(it);
              }

              else
              {
                     std::cout <<" we are deleting from copy_vector  when there is no match for rules " << std::endl ;
                      it =  copy_vector.erase(it);
              }
              std::cout <<" the size of copy _vector is = " << copy_vector.size() << std::endl ;

          }
          else
          {
              std::cout <<" No Match" << std::endl;
              // increase main iterator 
              if( it != copy_vector.end() )
             {
                     ++it;
             }
          }
      }

  }
  //print value
    for( std::vector< Subject >::iterator ii = copy_vector.begin() ; ii != copy_vector.end() ; ++ii )
    {

        std::cout <<" New list = " << ii->get_category <<" \t " << ii->get_sub_category() << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution has time complexity O(n*n) but the problem can be solved with complexity O(n*log(n)) or even O(n).

First, let's define such category comparison function (if a category is "Land" or "Jungle" then it's greater then other categories):

```
bool CategoryLess(string sCategory1, string sCategory2){
    return sCategory1 != "Land" && sCategory1 != "Jungle"
        && (sCategory2 == "Land" || sCategory2 == "Jungle");
}
```

Now iterate through the vector and store all found subcategories and corresponding Subjects in a `std::unordered_map` (or `std::map` in if you don't use C++11). If the subcategory is already in the `map` then replace corresponding `Subject` if the category of the already found `Subject` less then category of the new `Subject`:

```
unordered_map<string, Subject*> Subcategories;

for (int i=0; i<sub_vec.size(); ++i){
    unordered_map<string, Subject*>::iterator
        it = Subcategories.find(sub_vec[i].get_sub_category());  

    if (it != Subcategories.end()){
        if (CategoryLess((*it)->get_category(), sub_vec[i].get_category())
            it->second = &sub_vec[i];
    }
    else
        Subcategories[sub_vec[i].get_sub_category()] = &sub_vec[i];
}
```

Now you have the map of all subcategories and corresponding `Subject`s.
If we found two or more `Subject`s with the same subcategory then the map contains a pointer to the `Subject` with greater category.

Now iterate sub_vec once more and delete `Subject`s if

```
Subcategories[sub_vec[i].get_sub_category()] != &sub_vec[i];
```

**Time complexity:**
If we use `std::unordered_map` then expected time complexity is O(n) for the both cycles (O(n*n) in worst case).
If we use `std::map` then time complexity is O(n*log(n)) for the both cycles.

(I didn't take into account time complexities of string comparison and vector.erase as irrelevant)

**Please note** than when you delete a `Subject` from the vector, the addresses of other `Subject`s can be changed. So you need to take care when compare pointers to `Subject`s (for example copy needed `Subject`s to another vector instead of deleting other `Subject`s from the vector). But it doesn't change the general idea of my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I am in process of testing and incorporating your code in my project. Though I have encountered very silly error and I cant able to resolve it( may be because of my limited knowledge in STL) .  your line " if (CategoryLess((*it)->get_category(), sub_vec[i].get_category())" throw error  Expression must have pointer type. I guess with *it we  get  to sub_vec[it] and indirection points to data member . But somehow it doesn't work. May you please throw some light on it.

Comment: @samprat sorry for the typo. I should be `it->second->get_category()` instead of `(*it)->get_category()`.

Comment: Hi Mate, I have tested but when I print the vector it contains teh objects with duplicate sub_category. on deeper dig I found  it never hit  inside if condition.  if (CategoryLess((*it)->get_category(), sub_vec[i].get_category())
            it->second = &sub_vec[i]; // this line never get executed.

Comment: Also ALex I have a doubt with comparsion function. How wil the objects get deleted in case if category is neither land nor jungle . from my question condition 2.

Comment: @samprat I didn't try to compile the code so it can contain errors/typos. I only gave an general idea of my algorithm. If speaking about `CategoryLess()` then it should return `true` for e.g. `CategoryLess("Forest", "Land")` and `false` for e.g. `CategoryLess("Land", "Forest")` or `CategoryLess("Forest", "Forest")` or `CategoryLess("Land", "Land")`.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint inside CategoryLess and check what's happening in it.

Comment: @samprat the main idea of main solution is that `Subcategories` `map` should contain all unique subcategories and a single `Subject` for each subcategory that shouldn't be deleted from the `vector`. E.g. if we have the `Subject`s with categories Land, Forest, and Water and with the same subcategory then `Subcategories` `map` will contain only the `Subject` with category Land. And then `Subject`s with other categories (Forest and Water) will be deleted from the `vector`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for detailed explanation. I have struggled with this problem b t you made it look so nice. Your code works like a charm and moreover it gave me an understanding about  maps and all. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by using [remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). To check if an object has a duplicate sub_category you can use a function or functor that stores the subcategories it finds in a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or an [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and the remove all objects where its sub_category already exists in the set/unordered_map.

Note, unordered_map is only available in c++11.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks  buT i doubt remov_if will work. My issue is not with main object but with sub_category, if there are duplicate objects in  vector I can easily remove it but I dont want that. In my case its okay to have multiple objects with same name but I dont want 2 objects will have same sub_category.

Comment: @samprat you can still use std::remove_if to remove elements from the vector, but you would have to provide your own predicate function object to determine what elements to remove.

Comment: @samprat Just like YoungJohn says you can feed remove_if with a function/functor that checks this. I updated my answer with an idea about what that might look like.

Comment: @ simon , I have tried storing it in set ? but I couldnt able to acheive more

Answer (score 0):

Either you should use a lambda expression or define a functional object.

An example with using a lambda expression

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std:string tiger = "Tiger";

sub_vec.erase( std::remove_if( sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end(), 
                               [&]( const Subject &s ) { return ( s.sub_category == tiger ); } ),
               sub_vec.end() );
```

Take into account that the code above removes all obexts that have sub_category equal to "Tiger". If you need to remove only duplicates then at first you should find the first object of the sub category and then remove all other objects with the same subcategory. In this case the code could look as

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std:string tiger = "Tiger";

auto equal_sb_category = [&]( const Subject &s ) { return ( s.sub_category == tiger ); };

auto it = std::find_if( sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end(), equal_sb_category );

if ( it != sub_vec.end() )
{
    sub_vec.erase( std::remove_if( std::next( it ), sub_vec.end(), equal_sb_category ),
                   sub_vec.end() ); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Vlad,  Std::String tiger is not known in my case. What I meant earlier I need some way to compare sub_catogory  of instance of SUbjects. So I can have sub_vec form 0 to 3 elements  with say 4 objects with all objecyts having  name "Land" all have different sub_cateogry say man, woman, male , female , child , Similarly, nexct 3 elemets say from 4to 6 in sub_vector has  saaame object name say "Panther" and have  sub_category say panther_0 panther_1 , female.

Comment: Now in my sub_vector I have 2 objects panther & land that has " female" as sub_category so I want to remove one  of them based on certain criteria.

Comment: @samprat  You can specify any condition in the lanbda expression I showed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use BOOST_FOREACH to iterate thru vector elements

I'm doing something similar like this :

```
BOOST_FOREACH( Subject f, sub_vec )
{
    ///TODO: do your filtering here 
    if(f.sub_category == "<bla bla>")
}
```

What I like about using BOOST_FOREACH is that it makes very readable code and when you are dealing with many vector elements and many filtering possibilities, then that is certainly a factor to consider

Comment: HI serup , I am aware of these methods , My main worry is I dnt know  " <bla  bla >" ) . what i want is in my vector there are many objects , some of them have same name also which is fine . All I want is my vector should'nt have objects that have name sub_category. SO exampel I can have 5 vectors with objects , Animal, Animal, Land, Car, Car. but if say Animal->sub_category & Car->sub_category matches then remove one of them .

Comment: so say Based on some criteria  I removed car so now I left with Animal, Animal,Land , Car. This time all have unique sub_category. that what I want? and for that I need some comparing algo

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand you.
In order to compare you need to know the value of what you are comparing, so when you say you do not know "<bla bla>", which is just a placeholder for the value you want to compare with, then how will you find your elements (subjects) with same value?

You further explain somewhat and it seems that what you want is exactly what you can get with this BOOST_FOREACH, its a for loop running through each Subject f, which is based on the sub_vec type and values from sub_vec, so f.sub_category will be one of the Subjects from sub_vec, so now compare

Comment: The smart thing about using BOOST_FOREACH like this, instead of a lambda function combined with find, is that it is much easier to read and understand for you one month later -- using lambda functions are smart, but could be costly later down the line when you have to change your code.

Comment: In order to "fetch" the <bla bla> values, then you could run throug all Subjects and create a list of categories, then filter to only have the ones that where duplicated, then run through subjects again and compare with the duplicated list, then remove.
I think I finally understood your issue ;-)  I hope I helped

Comment: I think perhaps above lambda solution is doing all this, if you add something like std::prev( it ) in the compare part, now you need to decide if you want it in your code ( with extra comments to understand it later on ) or you want to try and build this BOOST_FOREACH version -- good luck with it, and perhaps post your final solution

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for detailed explanation.  I do not have much knowledge about boost but certainly I will try to expand my knowledge in it.  At the moment , I have choosen sample by Alex and twick it according to my requirements.